# Basic javascript code layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have what I think is a fairly simply question but it's one that I can not find the answer to. I have a objects literal that I have created that groups functions, I want to know how I can create a variable that is inside the objects literal and editable/accessable by all the functions within that objects literal. At the moment the only way I know how to do this is create a global variable but I want to stop populating the global in this way. To better describe what I'm looking fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aT3J6/

Thanks, for any help.

```
var clickCount = 0;

/* I would like to place clickCount inside hideShowFn Object but all function inside need access to it, so global within hideShowFn */

hideShowFn = {
    init:function(){  
     $('.clickMe').click(this.addToCount);                
    },

addToCount:function(){
    clickCount++;
    $('<p>'+ clickCount + '</p>').appendTo('body');
    }
}

hideShowFn.init();
```

Comment: Can you wrap all that code in a function?

Comment: If you wrap all the code inside of a closure `(function() { ... })();` it will keep the global scope clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which is invoked immediately and returns the object, with the private variable inside the function, like this:

```
var obj = (function () {
    var privateStuff = 'private';
    return {
        func1: function () { 
            //do stuff with private variable
        },
        func2: function () {
            //do stuff with private variable
        }
    };
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BE3WZ/

This is the way to have private variables in [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused about how this would works. I would be very grateful if you could work it back into the fiddle???

Comment: I've edited my answer, explaining my method a bit and giving a link to a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/aT3J6/10/

Another option would be the pseudo-classical style:

```
function Constructor(){
  var private = 'private';
  this.public = 'public';

  this.methods = {
    //your methods here...
  };
}

var obj = new Constructor();
```

Don't forget to use the 'new' keyword, or else you are going to be globally scoped.

Your code translated to this style would be:

```
function Test(){
  var that = this,
      clickCount = 0;

  this.init = function(){
    $('.clickMe').click(this.addToCount);
  };

  this.addToCount = function(){
    clickCount++;
    $('<p>'+ clickCount + '</p>').appendTo('body');
  };
}

var test = new Test();
test.init();
```

Comment: Why would he need a constructor to make this object? He obviously needs only one copy of it...

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions either way. OP was curious about how to control scope. My answer shows another way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a closure as [Cokegod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942519/887539) says or you can simply add the variable to the object and access it using `this`

```
hideShowFn = {
    clickCount: 0,
    init:function(){  
        $('.clickMe').click(this.addToCount);                
    },
    addToCount:function(){
        this.clickCount++;
        $('<p>'+ this.clickCount + '</p>').appendTo('body');
    }
}

hideShowFn.init();
```

**This dosn't work as Musa says the scope in `addToCount` will be the dom node clicked.**

But see Cokegod's answer.

Comment: When `addToCount` is called as a click handler `this` will refer to the `.clickMe` element and not the object `hideShowFn `

Comment: You'll have to call the original namespace in the click function `hideShowFn.clickCount` ..